# Output not seeing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I have two files for tic-tac-toe. One is **game.py** and another one is **player.py**.

After running my main file that is game.py, I'm seeing the blank in my shell.

I've added the **for _ in range(1000):**

Also, I've added the minimax algorithm.

**player.py:**

```
#separate player in two classes, for this is x and y player

    import math
    import random

    class Player:
    
    def __init__(self,letter):
        
    # letter is x or 0
    self.letter = letter
        # we want player to guess their next move
        
    def get_move(self,game):
        pass
    
# super() function allow access to super class method in child classes 
class randomcomputer_player(Player):
    def __init__(self,letter):
        super().__init__(letter)
        
    def get_move(self,game):
        square = random.choice(game.available_moves())
        return square
    
    class human_player(Player):
    def __init__(self,letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    # human_player will guess their next move

    def get_move(self,game):
        valid_square = False
        val = None
        while not valid_square:
            square = input(self.letter + 'x or o turn. Input move from (0-8)')
            try:
                val = int(square)    #square is a value that user put
                if val not in game.available_moves():
                    raise ValueError
                valid_square = True      #if this steps are valid
            except ValueError:           #This excepts value error
                print('Invalid square. Try again: ')

                #once we got valid square
        return val

    # define a minimax algorithm to find the minimax steps

    class GeniusComputerPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self,letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    # computer is going to take moves. so

    def get_move(self,game):
        if len(game.available_moves()) == 9:
            square = random.choice(game.available_moves()) #randomly choose
        else: 
            # get the square box of the minimax algorithm
            # Below line shows that only computer wins
            square = self.minimax(game,self.letter)['position']
        return square
       
    def minimax(self,state,player):
        max_player = self.letter # yourself wins
        other_player = 'o' if player == 'x' else 'x'
        
        # we want to check if previous move is winner
        if state.current_winner == other_player:
            return {'position':None,'score':1*(state.num_empty_square()+1) if other_player == 
                     max_player else -1*(state.num_empty_square()+1)}
        
        elif not state.empty_square():    # No empty square
            return {'position':None,'score':0}
        
        # Intialize some dictionaries

        if player == max_player: # this max_player is yourself
            # I didn't get this line
            # you want to maximize every single time step
            # comparing every single score to this score, and you're trying to incrementwe     #want 
              to intialize it with lowest possible score i.e. -e
            best = {'position':None,'score':-math.inf} # Each score should maximize
            
        else:
            #player isn't max player
            # value started at infinity because we want to decrement the value to it

            best = {'position':None,'score':math.inf}
            
        for possible_moves in state.available_moves():
            # step1 : Make a move and try that spots
            state.make_move(possible_moves,player)
            # step2 : recurse using minimax to simulate a game after making that move
            sim_score = self.minimax(state,other_player) # now we alternate players
            
            # That means what happens if we make that move
            # step3: Undo the moves, so we can try next one in future iteration
            state.board[possible_moves] = ' ' # possible move set to empty square
            # set current_winner to None that means nobody has won
            state.current_winner = None
            sim_score['position'] = possible_moves
            
            # step4 : Update the dictionaries if neccessary
            if player == max_player:
                if sim_score['score']>best['score']:
                    best = sim_score # replace best with simulated score, moving to increment
            else:
                #your player is min_player, that means sim_score has low value
                if sim_score['score']<best['score']:
                    best = sim_score
        return best
```

**game.py**:

```
#This file will create a 3x3 board
    import time
    from player import human_player,randomcomputer_player,GeniusComputerPlayer
    class TicTacToe():
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = self.make_board() #we will use single list for 3 x 3 board
        self.current_winner = None      #keep track of current winner
        
    @staticmethod
    def make_board():
        return [' ' for _ in range(9)]

    def print_board(self):
        #getting each position in row
        for row in [self.board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
        #-->row --->1  if 0, then self.board[0:3], 0 1 2 when range = 0
        #-->row --->2  if 1, then self.board[3:6], 3 4 5 when range = 1
        #-->row --->3  if 2, then self.board[6:9], 6 7 8 when range = 2
            print('|' +'|'.join(row)+'|')
    #static method can't modify, it's independent from other class, not require class method         
    instatnce
    @staticmethod
    def print_board_num():
        #0|1|2 etc tells us what number correspond to what box
        number_board = [[str(i) for i in range(j*3,(j+1)*3)] for j in range(3)]
        for row in number_board:
            print('|'+'|'.join(row)+'|')
            
    def available_moves(self):
        return [i for (i,spot) in enumerate(self.board) if spot == ' ']
            #['x','x',o'---> [(0,'x'),(1,'x'),(2,'o')]
            #if spot == ' ':
               # moves.append(i)
            #return moves
               
    def empty_square(self):
        return ' ' in self.board
    #keep track of empty square
    def num_empty_square(self):
        return self.board.count(' ')
    
    def make_move(self,square,letter):
        #square the place if valid also, the valid letter
        if self.board[square] == ' ':
            self.board[square] = letter
            if self.winner(square, letter):
                self.current_winner = letter  # current_winner depends on letter
                
            return True
        return False
    # Create a function for check the winner
    def winner(self,square,letter):
        # winner if 3 rows anywhere
        # The 3 letters can be row, column and diagoniall
        # first check for row letters
        row_ind = square//3     # square starts with 0
        row = self.board[row_ind:(row_ind+1)*3]
        # print('row',row)
        if all([spot == letter for spot in row]):
            return True # if all spots filled with letter
        
        # if all spots are not filled then
        # filled the column, we need column value
        col_ind = square % 3 #add column index with
        col = [self.board[col_ind+i*3] for i in range(3)]
        # print('col : ',col)
        if all([spot == letter for spot in col]):
            return True
        
        # if patterns doesn't come row or column then use diagonally
        if square%2 == 0:
            diagonal1 = [self.board[i] for i in [0,4,8]] #for left to right diagonal
            if all([spot == letter for spot in diagonal1]):
                return True
            
            diagonal2 = [self.board[i] for i in [2,4,6]] #for right to left diagonal
            if all([spot == letter for spot in diagonal2]):
                return True
            
        #if all of the checks fail, so no winner
        return False
    
    def play(game,x_player,o_player,print_game= True):
    # return a winner if one or None for tie
    if print_game:
        game.print_board_num()
        
    letter = 'x' #starting letter
    # while game has empty squares
    while game.empty_square():
        # get the move from approiate player
        if letter == 'o':
            square = o_player.get_move(game)
        else:
            square = x_player.get_move(game)
            #let's define a function to make a move
            
        if game.make_move(square,letter):
            if print_game:
                print(letter+f" makes a move to square {square}")
                game.print_board()  #new representation of spot claimed by user
                print(' ')     # printing the empty line
                
            if game.current_winner:
                if print_game:
                    print(letter+"win")
                return letter
                # after we made our move, we need to alternate our letter
            letter = "o" if letter == "x" else "x"
                #we've to check who wins, so. we'll win after a move
            #if no next steps and nobody wins then tie
            # give tiny break
        if print_game: 
            time.sleep(0.8)
                
    if print_game:
        print("It's a tie!")
          # This module is running as main file.
          
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_wins = 0
    o_wins = 0
    ties = 0
    for _ in range(1000):
         # imported the player
        x_player = randomcomputer_player('x')
        o_player = GeniusComputerPlayer('o')
         # Create a instance
        t = TicTacToe()
         # call a play function to execute the game
        result = play(t,x_player,o_player,print_game=False)
        if result == "x":
            x_wins+=1
        elif result == "o":
            o_wins+=1
        else:
            ties+=1
        
    print(f'After 1000 iterations we see {x_wins} x_wins, {o_wins} o wins, and {ties} ties')
```

After, running my main file that is game.py I'm seeing the blank output, why?

Comment: This is a very long piece of code, but also doens't include `game.py`. It will take someone a lot of time to read, understand and debug it. Please try to cut this down to the shortest amount of code that displays the bug, and edit your question.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a moment to revisit the [ask] and [mre], as well as related help page. Dumping 288 lines of malformed code as people makes it very hard for volunteers to help you. You can [edit] your question to help us help you.

Comment: I tried to run your code it was trouble to re-indent your code and see whats going on. I run your code and it has some outputs (and receives input) but I have no idea whether this is right or not. Please add more details to your question and include the two files with proper format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you deliberately chose not to show any output in your console

```
result = play(t,x_player,o_player,print_game=False)
```

If you change the print_game variable to True it will start printing the games as expected.